# Create new column in df with value from a dictionary based on column vale

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to create a new column in a dataframe and fill with a value from a dictionary based on the value of another column.

my dictionary is

```
artist_pop_dic = df_fe.artist.value_counts().to_dict()
```

the command I am writing is

```
df_fe["artist_popularity"] = artist_pop_dic[df_fe["artist"]]
```

The error message I am getting is

```
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

can someone help please. Thanks

Comment: the artist column includes names of artist and the dictionary is the count of songs each artist has in the df

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
>>> l = ['ABC','NHB','KLM','ABC','NBN','MNM','ABC','NHB','KLM']
>>> l
['ABC', 'NHB', 'KLM', 'ABC', 'NBN', 'MNM', 'ABC', 'NHB', 'KLM']
>>> 

>>> df = pd.DataFrame(l,columns=['Artist'])
>>> df
  Artist
0    ABC
1    NHB
2    KLM
3    ABC
4    NBN
5    MNM
6    ABC
7    NHB
8    KLM

>>> df['Popularity'] = df['Artist'].apply(lambda x:artist_pop_dic[x])
>>> df
  Artist  Popularity
0    ABC           3
1    NHB           2
2    KLM           2
3    ABC           3
4    NBN           1
5    MNM           1
6    ABC           3
7    NHB           2
8    KLM           2
```

Another approach would be to use `groupby` on your `artist` column and merge it back with the main dataframe

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(l,columns=['Artist'])
>>> pd.merge(df,df.groupby('Artist').size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'Popularity'}),on=['Artist'])
  Artist  Popularity
0    ABC           3
1    ABC           3
2    ABC           3
3    NHB           2
4    NHB           2
5    KLM           2
6    KLM           2
7    NBN           1
8    MNM           1
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work. Thanks

```
df_fe["artist_popularity"]=(df_fe['artist']).apply(lambda x: artist_pop_dic[x])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `map` for this.

```
import pandas as pd

counts = {
    'bob':3,
    'sam':10,
    'lisa':99
}

df = pd.DataFrame({'artist':['bob','bob','alex','sam','lisa']})


df['counts'] = df.artist.map(counts)

print(df)
```

Output

```
  artist  counts
0    bob     3.0
1    bob     3.0
2   alex     NaN
3    sam    10.0
4   lisa    99.0
```